# Finding missing keys in a QMap

Tags: qt, qmap

I have a `qmap` of `<int , Myclass*>`

The key has a range of `1` to `n_max`.

When I insert into the map I need to know the lowest available unused key.

For example if the map contains

> <1, obj1>
>
> <3, obj3>

When I insert my next item in the map, I would want allocate the key to be 2

Whats the most efficient way of doing this

Regards

Comment: There are many ways to do that, but it is not very efficient. If you told us how the keys are created, we could maybe give you a better approach than QMap.

Comment: those "holes" are depending by deletion of some objects or they depend by insertion of casual keys also?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do a few things in order to optimize the search.

First, check the `count()` against something like map.end()'s previous record (ie, --).  If they're the same you know it's full and can add at the end.

If they're not (the end iterator value is greater than the `count()`), then you know you need to search for a hole.  When searching for a whole, you'll likely want to pull out all the `uniqueKeys()` and then start searching at the middle of it to see if the middle key matches the previous `count()/2` or so.  If not, go down further by another `count()/4`, otherwise go up by `count()/4`.  Repeat until you find what you're looking for.

But really, I'm not sure a map is the right container in the first place.  It sounds like you need an array or linked list or...  it depends on your data.  But if you need to do the above operation with a map I suggest you probably need to find the right container.

Answer (score 0):

Since QMap keeps items sorted by key, you could use adjacent_find algorithm from the c++ standard library:

```
#include <QMap>
#include <algorithm>

bool missing (int i, int j) {
  return (i+1 < j);
}

int next_key(const QMap<int,int>& map) {
  if (!map.size()) 
    return 1; // or 0, if an acceptable key value

  QList<int>::iterator i = std::adjacent_find(map.keys().begin(), map.keys().end(), missing);

  if (i==map.keys().end()) // no missing values found
    --i; 

  return *i + 1;
}
```

Complexity is exactly the smaller of (result - first) + 1 and (last - first) - 1 applications of the predicate ("missing" function) where result is the return value.